# Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.Cron is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, meteor, cron

I'd like to use [mrt/cron](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/cron) on Meteor. I typed the following code in `client/index.js`, however it returned `Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.Cron is not a constructor`. How can I solve the problem?

```
var helloWorld = function () {
       console.log('hello world');
  }
  new Meteor.Cron({
    events: {
       "* * * * *": helloWorld
    }
  });
```

Comment: Crons really should run on the server and not the client as the client can come and go.

Answer (score 2):

This package currently [adds the source file on the server only](https://github.com/alexsuslov/Meteor.cron/blob/master/package.js).

This means that the constructor will not be available on the client.

That said, you can easily fork the package locally and add the source file to the client. I don't see anything that will prevent it from working there.